# Noun 'stuff' and the preposition for the verb 'do' in the phrase

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-verbs

I have to express something and I'd like to use `stuff` noun. The problem is a proper use `do` verb when doing is related to something.

My phrase is `Some privilege stuff should be done to it`. I use it for my tutorial about server configuration. Maybe `done with it`?

The phrase should mean that some work must be done to make a certain directory on the disk accessible for some users or not.

Comment: _"done to it"_ , but **do** is too general a verb, imo. Maybe _"applied to it"_ ?

Comment: The use of *privilege* is strange. First of all, it should be *privileged* if it's being used as an adjective . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence

> Some privilege stuff should be done to it.

might be better served as

> Some privilege**s** stuff should be done to it.

Since in the the devops worlds "***priviledges***" has a specific meaning of allowing or removing rights.
It is obvious from your description the "***it***" refers to the directory.

> The priviledges need to be configured on that directory as...

Would be the clearest way of expressing what you are trying to get across.